# Golang WebServer on windows xp can not handle http request any more after running for a while

Tags: windows, http, go, freeze

I recently used go language to develop a web server on windows xp.
**After running for a while, the go web can not handle any request from client**.
I checked the go routine scheduler, it works because I have a timer task and it runs well.And no log tells me there is deadlock. I am confused, why go web can not receive any request.

#### The stuck goroutine trace as follow

```
<code>
goroutine 1495590 [running]:
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutineStacks(0x324e0100, 0x11ad6060, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:516 +0x84
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine(0x324e0100, 0x11ad6060, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:505 +0x3c
runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo(0xc71770, 0x324e0100, 0x11ad6060, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:236 +0xb4
github.com/astaxie/beego/toolbox.ProcessInput(0x11b3a110, 0x10, 0x324e0100, 0x11ad6060)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/toolbox/profile.go:42 +0x2fd
github.com/astaxie/beego.profIndex(0x324e0068, 0x11838080, 0x117de000)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/admin.go:275 +0x147
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa3e7f4, 0x324e0068, 0x11838080, 0x117de000)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x34
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x11683cc0, 0x324e0068, 0x11838080, 0x117de000)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1699 +0x133
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x1189c080, 0x324e0068, 0x11838080, 0x117de000)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x156
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x11ad6000)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xc05
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343

goroutine 1 [chan receive, 127 minutes]:
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run(0x1169e550)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:182 +0x85a
github.com/astaxie/beego.Run(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/beego.go:66 +0x130
main.main()
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/rayingtech/restaurant/main.go:53 +0x27

goroutine 17 [syscall, 127 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    c:/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1662 +0x1

goroutine 5 [syscall, 127 minutes]:
os/signal.loop()
    c:/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x1a
created by os/signal.init.1
    c:/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x36

goroutine 6 [chan receive, 127 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0x116deb40)
    c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:634 +0x3c
created by database/sql.Open
    c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:481 +0x276

goroutine 7 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995d40, 0x72, 0x11b3a070)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x118aa0d0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x118aa038, 0x962b48, 0x8, 0x11b3a060, 0x11b822a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).acceptOne(0x118aa000, 0x11b82000, 0x2, 0x2, 0x118aa038, 0x31690000, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:564 +0x1d4
net.(*netFD).accept(0x118aa000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:594 +0x11f
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0x11890018, 0x118c2e3c, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x47
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0x11890018, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x3d
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0x1189c080, 0x31995e30, 0x11890018, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0x98
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0x1189c080, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0xe4
net/http.ListenAndServe(0x11892020, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1967 +0x7a
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*adminApp).Run(0x1169e548)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/admin.go:419 +0x581
created by github.com/astaxie/beego.registerAdmin
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/hooks.go:90 +0x4d

goroutine 8 [IO wait, 3 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995db8, 0x72, 0x1184d840)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x11833870, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x118337d8, 0x962b48, 0x8, 0x1184d830, 0x119e8540, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).acceptOne(0x118337a0, 0x119e8460, 0x2, 0x2, 0x118337d8, 0x316904a8, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:564 +0x1d4
net.(*netFD).accept(0x118337a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:594 +0x11f
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0x118629a8, 0x118c5ea8, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x47
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0x118629a8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x3d
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0x11688f80, 0x31995e30, 0x118629a8, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0x98
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0x11688f80, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0xe4
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run.func4(0x1169e550, 0x11854c00, 0x5, 0x118841c0)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:174 +0x35c
created by github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:180 +0x83e

goroutine 9 [chan receive, locked to thread]:
net.(*ioSrv).ProcessRemoteIO(0x11862998)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:138 +0xcc
created by net.startServer
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:238 +0xc9

goroutine 10 [chan receive, 3 minutes, locked to thread]:
net.(*ioSrv).ProcessRemoteIO(0x118629a0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:138 +0xcc
created by net.startServer
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:240 +0x11e

goroutine 353800 [IO wait, 114 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995ae8, 0x72, 0x11b480e0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x1190b170, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x1190b0d8, 0x93ce80, 0x7, 0xa3ea10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).Read(0x1190b0a0, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:463 +0x129
net.(*conn).Read(0x117c3648, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xb9
net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read(0x11ad6684, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:219 +0x84
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x11b480b0, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x11685b90)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x172
bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0x11685b90, 0x1163380a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:328 +0x1b4
bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine(0x11685b90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:357 +0x4b
net/textproto.(*Reader).readLineSlice(0x11951a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/textproto/reader.go:55 +0x59
net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadLine(0x11951a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/textproto/reader.go:36 +0x39
net/http.ReadRequest(0x11685b90, 0x11b47340, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/request.go:653 +0x9a
net/http.(*conn).readRequest(0x11ad6660, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:633 +0x368
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x11ad6660)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1319 +0x7a9
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343

goroutine 1421744 [IO wait, 7 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995b60, 0x72, 0x11841650)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x119f0fb0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x119f0f18, 0x93ce80, 0x7, 0xa3ea10, 0x4c201b, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).Read(0x119f0ee0, 0x11aac000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:463 +0x129
net.(*conn).Read(0x11863570, 0x11aac000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xb9
net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read(0x1193d764, 0x11aac000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:219 +0x84
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x11893310, 0x11aac000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x27, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x11b0a060)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x172
bufio.(*Reader).Peek(0x11b0a060, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:132 +0xad
net/http.(*conn).readRequest(0x1193d740, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:629 +0x30e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x1193d740)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1319 +0x7a9
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343

goroutine 1495604 [IO wait, 3 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995908, 0x72, 0x11855690)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x119fda30, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x119fd998, 0x93ce80, 0x7, 0xa3ea10, 0x4027a5, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).Read(0x119fd960, 0x11968000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:463 +0x129
net.(*conn).Read(0x117c2fd0, 0x11968000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xb9
net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read(0x117077c4, 0x11968000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x449a00, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:219 +0x84
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x1184d220, 0x11968000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x11b6a120)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x172
bufio.(*Reader).Read(0x11b6a120, 0x11b68400, 0x21, 0x200, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:207 +0x1b9
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x11840ee0, 0x11b68400, 0x21, 0x200, 0x11b17994, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
net/http.(*body).readLocked(0x11a212f0, 0x11b68400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:632 +0x7f
net/http.(*body).Read(0x11a212f0, 0x11b68400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/transfer.go:624 +0xe8
net/http.(*expectContinueReader).Read(0x11840ef0, 0x11b68400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:569 +0x100
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x1184d510, 0x11b68400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0x11b17ab4, 0x32520080, 0x1184d510, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bytes/buffer.go:173 +0x1c3
io/ioutil.readAll(0x32520080, 0x1184d510, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:33 +0x136
io/ioutil.ReadAll(0x32520080, 0x1184d510, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go:42 +0x51
github.com/astaxie/beego/context.(*BeegoInput).CopyBody(0x11b38340, 0x4000000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/context/input.go:337 +0xd4
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*ControllerRegister).ServeHTTP(0x116edd60, 0x324e0068, 0x11ab1980, 0x11ae7b20)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/router.go:652 +0x2cc0
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x11688f80, 0x324e0068, 0x11ab1980, 0x11ae7b20)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x156
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x117077a0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xc05
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343
```

==============================================================

#### The normal goroutine trace as follows:

```
goroutine 1359760 [running]:
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutineStacks(0x324e0100, 0x117a3f80, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:516 +0x84
runtime/pprof.writeGoroutine(0x324e0100, 0x117a3f80, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:505 +0x3c
runtime/pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo(0xc71770, 0x324e0100, 0x117a3f80, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go:236 +0xb4
github.com/astaxie/beego/toolbox.ProcessInput(0x1194bc80, 0x10, 0x324e0100, 0x117a3f80)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/toolbox/profile.go:42 +0x2fd
github.com/astaxie/beego.profIndex(0x324e0068, 0x117e4080, 0x11a19340)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/admin.go:275 +0x147
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xa3e7f4, 0x324e0068, 0x117e4080, 0x11a19340)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x34
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x11683cc0, 0x324e0068, 0x117e4080, 0x11a19340)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1699 +0x133
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x1189c080, 0x324e0068, 0x117e4080, 0x11a19340)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x156
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x1197eea0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xc05
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343

goroutine 1 [chan receive, 98 minutes]:
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run(0x1169e550)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:182 +0x85a
github.com/astaxie/beego.Run(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/beego.go:66 +0x130
main.main()
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/rayingtech/restaurant/main.go:53 +0x27

goroutine 17 [syscall, 98 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    c:/go/src/runtime/asm_386.s:1662 +0x1

goroutine 5 [syscall, 98 minutes]:
os/signal.loop()
    c:/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x1a
created by os/signal.init.1
    c:/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x36

goroutine 6 [chan receive, 98 minutes]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0x116deb40)
    c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:634 +0x3c
created by database/sql.Open
    c:/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:481 +0x276

goroutine 7 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995d40, 0x72, 0x11b3b510)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x118aa0d0, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x118aa038, 0x962b48, 0x8, 0x11b3b500, 0x11abee00, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).acceptOne(0x118aa000, 0x11abed20, 0x2, 0x2, 0x118aa038, 0x31690254, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:564 +0x1d4
net.(*netFD).accept(0x118aa000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:594 +0x11f
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0x11890018, 0x118c2e3c, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x47
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0x11890018, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x3d
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0x1189c080, 0x31995e30, 0x11890018, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0x98
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0x1189c080, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0xe4
net/http.ListenAndServe(0x11892020, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1967 +0x7a
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*adminApp).Run(0x1169e548)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/admin.go:419 +0x581
created by github.com/astaxie/beego.registerAdmin
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/hooks.go:90 +0x4d

goroutine 8 [IO wait]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995db8, 0x72, 0x118e7640)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x11833870, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x118337d8, 0x962b48, 0x8, 0x118e7630, 0x118afce0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).acceptOne(0x118337a0, 0x118afc00, 0x2, 0x2, 0x118337d8, 0x31690000, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:564 +0x1d4
net.(*netFD).accept(0x118337a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:594 +0x11f
net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP(0x118629a8, 0x11960ea8, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254 +0x47
net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept(0x118629a8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2135 +0x3d
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0x11688f80, 0x31995e30, 0x118629a8, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1887 +0x98
net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe(0x11688f80, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1877 +0xe4
github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run.func4(0x1169e550, 0x11854c00, 0x5, 0x118841c0)
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:174 +0x35c
created by github.com/astaxie/beego.(*App).Run
    D:/goproject/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/app.go:180 +0x83e

goroutine 9 [chan receive, locked to thread]:
net.(*ioSrv).ProcessRemoteIO(0x11862998)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:138 +0xcc
created by net.startServer
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:238 +0xc9

goroutine 10 [chan receive, locked to thread]:
net.(*ioSrv).ProcessRemoteIO(0x118629a0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:138 +0xcc
created by net.startServer
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:240 +0x11e

goroutine 353800 [IO wait, 85 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x31995ae8, 0x72, 0x11b480e0)
    c:/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:157 +0x55
net.(*pollDesc).Wait(0x1190b170, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x35
net.(*ioSrv).ExecIO(0x11862998, 0x1190b0d8, 0x93ce80, 0x7, 0xa3ea10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:182 +0x122
net.(*netFD).Read(0x1190b0a0, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/fd_windows.go:463 +0x129
net.(*conn).Read(0x117c3648, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/net.go:172 +0xb9
net/http.(*liveSwitchReader).Read(0x11ad6684, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:219 +0x84
io.(*LimitedReader).Read(0x11b480b0, 0x1196e000, 0x1000, 0x1000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/io/io.go:427 +0xcb
bufio.(*Reader).fill(0x11685b90)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97 +0x172
bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice(0x11685b90, 0x1163380a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:328 +0x1b4
bufio.(*Reader).ReadLine(0x11685b90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:357 +0x4b
net/textproto.(*Reader).readLineSlice(0x11951a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/textproto/reader.go:55 +0x59
net/textproto.(*Reader).ReadLine(0x11951a40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/textproto/reader.go:36 +0x39
net/http.ReadRequest(0x11685b90, 0x11b47340, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/request.go:653 +0x9a
net/http.(*conn).readRequest(0x11ad6660, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:633 +0x368
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x11ad6660)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1319 +0x7a9
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343
```

- Go sdk:1.5
- compile platform : windows 8
- target platform: windows xp
- third party framework: beego

Comment: Does it work running on another platform? Does it work with the current version of Go?

Comment: No, I change it to the 1.6.1, it still stuck.

Comment: Are you closing your connections when you're done with them? Sounds like the OS might be running out of network handles. Some code would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: How do I know if  I ran out the handler or connection, is there any way to find out what is going on?

Comment: Find a way to reproduce the bug. Use a tool to send 1000 request Go web server, and

Comment: the way reproducing http server hang issue is still not very clear. I doubt it maybe go http library bug.

Comment: Now i used a nginx in front of the goweb server to handle the connection, it seems ok,but still need to test.